# What replaces org.hibernate.util.PropertiesHelper

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a legacy web app and my task is to upgrade the products and frameworks used in the legacy app. I found a use of class `PropertiesHelper` from package ***org.hibernate.util***. I found package ***org.hibernate.util*** in  `hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar` and not in versions of Hibernate from 4.0.0 and newer.

Does anyone know where `PropertiesHelper` was moved, or what replaces it in newer versions of Hibernate, at least Hibernate version 5.2.16 or newer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `Hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final-sources.jar` in Project Structure (see screenshot) and then could add a Maven dependency when I have Hibernate-code-5.2.16 in my POM.
Now, it's compiling and running.[image: Code Compiled with No errors]
[image: Adding Hibernate-code-3.6.10.Final-sources.jar into Project Structure]